# Imap_sort is not returning result we are waiting for

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to get mails using imap_sort. 
My email adresse contain a lot of related email box. 
Example: xxxx@gmail.com i'm applying imap_sort on is related to xxx@hotmail.com and is related to xxx@mydomain.com.
The result i get is only for those related to xxx@gmail.com and not related to other accounts even the mail exist in my gmail acoount.

The code i'm using actually:

```
$result = imap_sort($mail,SORTSIZE ,0,SE_UID,$search_criteria);
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
      extract_mail($mail,$value);
}
```

$search_criteria contain is FROM an email and is TO an email.
What i need actually is to extract all mail FROM and TO this mail even if the communication is between other accounts but exist in gmail with different alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: We have to use the **All** Folder and not the default folder whish is **Inbox** when connecting using imap_connect.